Modelling a Ball Screw Spindle for rotary and translatoric motion in simulink driveline
I have got a current problem to overcome, within a simulation of a Scara robot with Matlab/Simulink - Simscape Driveline. The THK bns-v allows rotary and translational motion. For only translational motion I can use the "leadscrew" block which works totally fine. But in the case, when there is a rotation and a translational movement, I have to add the rotary movement to the spindle up. But still the spindle shouldn’t position any further as the “normal” translational movement. Can anyone help me how these kind of mechanics can be modelled in Simscape.
Thank you so much, I’m looking forward to the answers.
Best Regards
Stephen
Model with CVT
I already tried to use a cvt and simply change its gear ratio. But when the movments get to zero i run into errors because i divede through zero.
